# SQL query optimisation

Tags: sql

I'd like to optimise the following statements, preferably into a single query if possible:

> SELECT * FROM a WHERE status = 'x' AND a_date < NOW() ORDER BY a_date ASC LIMIT 1;
>   SELECT * FROM a WHERE status = 'y' ORDER BY a_date ASC LIMIT 1;

where the second statement should only be evaluated if the first returns NULL.

I have indexing set up correctly, this is more a question of can I issue a single statement instead of issuing a secondary statement after an application logic check for the null object.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: There's a homework tag, if your question fits the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE (status = 'x' AND a_date < NOW()) OR (status = 'y')
ORDER BY status ASC, a_date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Here you rely on the fact that status 'x' will come before status 'y' in the natural order (if it's the other way around, change ASC with DESC in `ORDER BY status`.